# c# linq join on a sublist in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I have a list:  `var_assets_root` that has a nested sub list: `contents`.  I can do a join on the root list and augment it with extra items from the two other lists `lst_invtypes_assets` and `lst_stations_composite_retribution` by doing two joins on index items in `var_assets_root`.  But I also want to do a join on the items that are within the sublist `var_assets_root-->contents\b.contents` which the code below is not doing so far.
[Image>>structure of `var_assets_root` in watch window](http://i152.photobucket.com/albums/s178/xav2075/stackoverflow_linq_sublist_join_problem_zps6342848d.jpg)

```
mysql mysql_object = new mysql();
  List<mysql.invtypes_asset> lst_invtypes_assets = mysql_object.dbmysql_invtypes_asset_to_list();
  List<mysql.stations_composite_retribution> lst_stations_composite_retribution = mysql_object.dbmysql_select_stastations_composite_retribution_to_list();
  var lst_assets_list = new AssetList("134399", "343434SxSFX7qO81LqUCberhS1OQtktMvARFGED0ZRSN5c4XP230SA", "434367527");
  lst_assets_list.Query();
  var var_assets_root = lst_assets_list.assets.ToList();

  var var_assets_root_typeid_station 
    = from b in var_assets_root
    join c in lst_invtypes_assets on b.typeID equals c.typeID
    join d in lst_stations_composite_retribution on b.locationID equals d.stationID
    select new {b.contents, b.flag, b.itemID, b.locationID, d.solarSystemName, d.security, d.securityClass, d.regionName, b.quantity, b.singleton, b.typeID, c.groupID, c.marketGroupID, c.volume,
      c.typeName, c.description};
```

I have done a solution of running a linq query for every content sub list and assigning values accordingly.

```
private void btn_evenet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
  Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
  stopwatch1.Start();
  mysql mysql_object = new mysql();
  List<mysql.invtypes_asset> lst_invtypes_assets = mysql_object.dbmysql_invtypes_asset_to_list();
  List<mysql.stations_composite_retribution> lst_stations_composite_retribution = mysql_object.dbmysql_select_stastations_composite_retribution_to_list();
  AssetList lst_assets_list = new AssetList("2312099", "J&VNM14RFUkSxSFX7qAAAAAA1OQtktMvYTVZZBhkO23235c4Z&HJKODPQLM", "123231527");
  lst_assets_list.Query();
  var var_assets_root = lst_assets_list.assets.ToList();
  var var_assets_root_typeid_station 
    = from b in var_assets_root
    join c in lst_invtypes_assets on b.typeID equals c.typeID
    join d in lst_stations_composite_retribution on b.locationID equals d.stationID
      select new { b.contents, b.flag, b.itemID, b.locationID, d.solarSystemName, d.security, d.securityClass, d.regionName, b.quantity, b.singleton, b.typeID, c.groupID, c.marketGroupID, c.volume,
      c.typeName, c.description};
  var lst_assets_root_typeid_station = var_assets_root_typeid_station.ToList(); // Using .ToArray() is about 200ms faster than .ToList()
  stopwatch2.Start(); 
  for (Int32 a = 0; a < lst_assets_root_typeid_station.Count(); a++)
  {
    if (lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents.Count() >= 0)
    {
      for (Int32 b = 0; b < lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents.Count(); b++)
      {
        var var_row_invtypes_assets = lst_invtypes_assets.Where(x => x.typeID == lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].typeID).ToArray();
        lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].groupID = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].groupID;
        lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].typeName = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].typeName;
        lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].description = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].description;
        lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].volume = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].volume;
        lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].marketGroupID = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].marketGroupID;
        if (lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents.Count() != 0)
        {
          for (Int32 c = 0; c < lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents.Count(); c++)
          {
            var_row_invtypes_assets = lst_invtypes_assets.Where(x => x.typeID == lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents[c].typeID).ToArray();
            lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents[c].groupID = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].groupID;
            lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents[c].typeName = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].typeName;
            lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents[c].description = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].description;
            lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents[c].volume = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].volume;
            lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[b].contents[c].marketGroupID = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].marketGroupID;
          }
        }
      }         
    }
  }
  stopwatch2.Stop();
  stopwatch1.Stop();
  lbl_stopwatch1.Text = "Everything: " +  stopwatch1.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff"); // 1.53 seconds no debugging
  lbl_stopwatch2.Text = "contents sublists: " +  stopwatch2.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff"); // contents sublists take 1.03 seconds no debugging
}
 }
```

Once I figured that 'yield' pops one content node from a stack of content nodes when  getAllContents is called I adapted my code and your function so that now all content nodes get recursed into and have their empty values filled from a linq query.  Also the new code that is after the linq creation of var_assets_root_typeid_station is now almost twice as fast.  Thank you.

```
private void btn_evenet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
  Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
  stopwatch1.Start();
  mysql mysql_object = new mysql();
  List<mysql.invtypes_asset> lst_invtypes_assets = mysql_object.dbmysql_invtypes_asset_to_list();
  List<mysql.stations_composite_retribution> lst_stations_composite_retribution = mysql_object.dbmysql_select_stastations_composite_retribution_to_list();
  AssetList lst_assets_list = new AssetList("12345678", "ABCDEFFGHIKL01235kokJDSD213123", "12345678");
  lst_assets_list.Query();
  var var_assets_root = lst_assets_list.assets.ToList();
  var var_assets_root_typeid_station 
    = from b in var_assets_root
    join c in lst_invtypes_assets on b.typeID equals c.typeID
    join d in lst_stations_composite_retribution on b.locationID equals d.stationID
      select new 
        {b.contents, b.flag, b.itemID, b.locationID, d.solarSystemName, d.security, d.securityClass, d.regionName, b.quantity, b.singleton, b.typeID, c.groupID, c.marketGroupID, c.volume,
      c.typeName, c.description};
  var lst_assets_root_typeid_station = var_assets_root_typeid_station.ToList(); // Using .ToArray() is about 200ms faster than .ToList()
  stopwatch2.Start(); 
 for (Int32 a = 0; a < lst_assets_root_typeid_station.Count(); a++)
  {
    if (lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents.Count() > 0)
    {
      for (Int32 z = 0; z < lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents.Count(); z++)
      {
        foreach (AssetList.Item contentnode in getAllContents(lst_assets_root_typeid_station[a].contents[z]))
        {
          var var_row_invtypes_assets = lst_invtypes_assets.Where(x => x.typeID == contentnode.typeID).ToArray();
          contentnode.groupID = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].groupID;
          contentnode.typeName = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].typeName;
          contentnode.description = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].description;
          contentnode.volume = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].volume;
          contentnode.marketGroupID = var_row_invtypes_assets[0].marketGroupID;
        }
      }
    }
  }    
  stopwatch2.Stop();
  stopwatch1.Stop();
  lbl_stopwatch1.Text = "Everything: " +  stopwatch1.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff"); // 1.16 seconds no debugging
  lbl_stopwatch2.Text = "contents sublists: " +  stopwatch2.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff"); // contents sublists take 0.63 seconds no debugging
}

IEnumerable<AssetList.Item> getAllContents(AssetList.Item contentNode)
{
  if (contentNode.contents.Count == 0)
  {
    yield return contentNode;
  }
  else
  {
    foreach (AssetList.Item subContentNode in contentNode.contents)
    {
      yield return subContentNode;
      foreach (AssetList.Item subSubContentNode in getAllContents(subContentNode))
        yield return subSubContentNode;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should really make an effort to conform with standard naming conventions.  It will make your code much easier to read.

Comment: @Servy maybe the poster's code is conforming to a standard naming convention for a particular group. However, I agree that some editing could be useful prior to posting to SO.

Comment: I am a hobbyist novice coder.  I used naming that was intuitive to myself.  In the future I will try to adopt standard naming conventions

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you just looking for SelectMany?

`var contents = lst_invtypes_assets.contents.SelectMany(x => x.contents);`

Comment: How could I use .SelectMany() within the linq query var var_assets_root_typeid_station = ... So I can do a join on the contents sublist.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're getting at is that you want to access the outer `.contents` property, and if it contains any `contents`, then access those, too, and so on... recursively.

While you could do this by defining a recursive `Func<AssetList.Item, IEnumerable<AssetList.Item>>` and a line of LINQ using `.Aggregate`, it will probably be easier/more readable to define your own recursive method.

```
IEnumerable<AssetList.Item> getAllContents(AssetList.Item station) {
    foreach (AssetList.Item subStation in station.contents) {
        yield return subStation;
        foreach (AssetList.Item subSubStation in getAllContents(substation))
            yield return subSubStation;
    }
}
```

You can then do a simple `foreach(var station in getAllContents(parentStation))`, or modify this to include the original station, make it an extension method, etc.